# What publicly available software do professional stock traders use for stock analysis?

Tags: software, trading, stock-analysis

What publicly available software do professional stock traders use for stock analysis? I assume they use something more advanced than Google Finance... right?

Comment: I've made this specific to stock analysis, to match your tag and so this question isn't too broad.

Comment: this might turn into a wiki

Answer (score 5):

[Factset also provides a host of tools for analysis](http://www.factset.com/products/im). Not many people know as they aren't as prevalent as Bloomberg.

[CapitalQ](https://www.capitaliq.com/Main3/oursolutions_research.aspx) and [Thomson Reuters](http://thomsonreuters.com/products_services/financial/financial_products/investment_management/fam_investment_research_analysis/) also provide analysis tools. Most of the market data providers also provide analysis tools to analyze the data they and others provide.

Answer (score 4):

[Bloomberg Professional](http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/) seems to be very popular. It provides any kind of data you can imagine. Analysis is a subjective interpretation of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Another one I have seen mentioned used is [Equity Feed](http://www.equityfeed.com/mxrgst/step1.jsp). It had varies levels of the software depending on the markets you want and can provide level 2 quotes if select that option.

http://stockcharts.com/ is also a great tool I see mentioned with lots of free stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/) is very popular, especially for researching individual companies.

[Market QA](http://thomsonreuters.com/products_services/financial/financial_products/a-z/MarketQA/) and [Factset](http://www.factset.com/) are popular for analyzing data.

Microsoft Excel and Matlab are very common for analyzing the data.  Lots of time traders will take data from Bloomberg, Market QA, Factset or where ever, and then actually preform their analytics in Excel or Matlab.

A lot of the brokers provide their own software to traders using their platform, and that software can also contain different tools to help the traders as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to analyze stocks and don't need the other features provided by Bloomberg and Reuters (e.g. derivatives and FX), you could also look at [WorldCap](http://worldcap.org), which is a mobile solution to analyze global stocks, at [FactSet](http://www.factset.com/) and [S&P CapitalIQ](https://www.capitaliq.com/home.aspx). 
*Please note that I am affiliated with WorldCap.*